# Write from Java generic T[] to DataOutput stream?

Tags: java, generics

Given a generic array `T[]`, where `T extends java.lang.Number`, I would like to write the array to a `byte[]`, using `ByteArrayOutputStream`. `java.io.DataOutput` (and an implementation such as `java.io.DataOutputStream` appears close to what I need, but there is no generic way to write the elements of the `T[]` array. I want to do something like

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(out);

for (T v : getData()) {
  dataOut.write(v); // <== uh, oh
}
```

but there is no generic `<T> void write(T v)` method on `DataOutput`.

Is there any way to avoid having to write a whole bunch of `isntanceof` spaghetti?

*Clarification*

The `byte[]` is being sent to a non-Java client, so object serialization isn't an option. I need, for example, the `byte[]` generated from a `Float[]` to be a valid `float[]` in C.

Comment: How do you want to write the number? For example, do you want to write an int as always four bytes, or as text, or...?

Comment: As @Thomas says, this rather depends on the encoding you want to use. You can do writeUTF(v.toString()) for example. Remember that however you write it you may need a way to determine which type was written.

Comment: Data output stream is only for primitives and strings, so you need an Object stream anyway if you want to stay on "object level".

Comment: Thank you all for the good suggestions. I left a significant requirement out of the first version of the question (no clarified above). Object serialization will not work, unfortunately.

Comment: @Barry Correct me if i'm wrong, but isent this at least very tricky to impossible since floats are represented differently in java/c?

Comment: @InsertNickHere, I believe Java floats are IEEE 754, so I hope we can work with them in any IEEE 754-compliant runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't. The `instanceof` "spaghetti" would have to exist somewhere anyway. Make a generic method that does that:

```
public <T> void write(DataOutputStream stream, T object) {
   // instanceofs and writes here
}
```

Comment: this is equivalent to `public void write(DataOutputStream stream, Object object)` Generics has no effect

Answer (score 3):

You can just use an `ObjectOutputStream` instead of a `DataOutputStream`, since all `Number`s are guaranteed to be serializable.

Comment: But how do you deserialize then not knowing what type your objects are?

Comment: Unfortunately, I left a significant constraint out of the first version of the question (now clarified above). Object serialization won't work, since this `byte[]` must be transferable to other languages (e.g. C).

Comment: In that case, you should really think about what you mean by `Number`s and why you want them to have arbitrary format. What kind of numbers do you expect? Only integers? floating point? rational? complex? When interfacing with other languages, you have to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to the last edit, I would try this approach (if its ugly or not).

1) Check per instanceof which type you have
2) Store it into a primitive and extract the bytes you need  (eg integer) like this (for the first two bytes)

```
    byte[] bytes = new byte[2];
    bytes[0]=(byte)(i>>8);
    bytes[1]=(byte)i;
```

3) Send it via the byte[] array
4) Get stuck because different c implementations use different amout of bytes for integer, so nobody can guarantee that the results will equal your initial numbers. e.g. how do you want to handle the 4 byte integer of java with 2 byte integers of c? How do you handle Long?

So...i don't see a way to do, but, im not an expert in this area....

Please correct me if im wrong. ;-)

Comment: We're transmitting bytes-per-value, endian, and format (e.g. IEEE 754) with the byte[], so we handle all of the conversion on the C side. I just want to be able to parse primitive values instead of implementing Java object deserialization in C ;-)

Comment: @Barry if i understand you correctly, than all you need to know is how to convert int/float into bytes? Or is it just that you dont like the instanceof thing, which you cant avoid in my knowledge?

Comment: Just wondering if there was a way to avoid the `instanceof` dance. A chain of if/else `instanceof` tests smells. It's too bad Number doesn't implement a `toByteArray()` method.